# creating a random (Gantt-ish) chart

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to write a test for one of my audio programs, and I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around this test setup. First, I've got a table of 60 rows by 10000 columns that needs to be filled. Each cell has a value of ON, OFF, or LEFT (meaning I have the same value as my nearest ON/OFF to my left). I want a random twenty to forty rows to be on at any given time. Each has to be on for a random 6 to 200 cells. The commands to set ON or OFF have to be ordered by row then column. I'm picturing a sparse dictionary coming out with a coordinate key and on/off value. What I don't understand is how store my ON/OFF cells such that I can easily determine if my current row is ON or OFF. Help? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further thought on this, I realized I could do it in two passes. Here's what I ended up with. Feel free to comment on this approach:

```
        var table = new byte[60, 10000];
        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            // we want at least half the row to be blank
            int j = 0;
            while(j < 10000)
            {
                var width = rand.Next(7, 200);
                j += width * 2;
                var vol = (byte)rand.Next(50, 125);
                for(int k = j - width; k < Math.Min(10000, j); k++)
                    table[i, k] = vol;
            }
        }

        var midiEvents = new List<BASS_MIDI_EVENT>();
        midiEvents.Add(new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_PROGRAM, 0, 0, 0, 0));

        for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            {
                var cur = (int)table[i, j];
                var left = j > 0 ? table[i, j - 1] : 0;
                if(cur > 0 && left == 0)
                {
                    cur <<= 8;
                    cur |= i + 33;
                    midiEvents.Add(new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_NOTE, cur, 0, j, 0));
                }
                else if(cur == 0 && left > 0)
                {
                    midiEvents.Add(new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_NOTE, i + 33, 0, j, 0));
                }
            }
        }
```